# How to roll back to original value iPropertyChanged? C#

Tags: c#

I have a datagrid in my xamarin form app and it got a editable column. The values in the column are from MySql database and user can change the value and store to db. I used IPropertyChanged interface to allow user make the changes to the value. There is one condition when editing the value. The new value must be equal or bigger than the original value. My problem is whenever I enter a value bigger than the original, I cannot edit the value again to previous value. For example, the original value is 10. The new value I enter is 30. If I want to change the value again and this time I set it to 20, it is not allowing me because now the original value is 30 not 10 and 20 is less than 30. How can I retain the original value and compare with it?

```
public int ActualReading
    {
        get
        {
            return _ActualReading;
        }

        set
        {

            if (value >= _ActualReading)
            {
            _ActualReading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ActualReading");

            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Meter readings should not be smaller than previous value.","Error","Ok");
            }

        }
    }

private void RaisePropertyChanged(String Name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)

            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
    }
```

Comment: Save it in a variable on first set?

Comment: From on when is your "first" value the one on which the measurements are supposed to be compared to? Would you allow changes to a originally higher than first value but lower than actual value after you save your data?

Comment: yes, I would allow it. It's like this, my datagrid have many rows. Each row have one field with original value from database. The original value can be edited but the edited value must be equal or bigger than original value. Let's say original is 10. Now I edit it to 30, then I move on to next row. If I come to the previously edited row, it will show 30. I cannot edit the value 30 to smaller number than 30 because now 30 have replaced 10 as original value in that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the original value. I'm using the following pattern.

Assuming you have a model like this

```
public class Model
{
    public int ActualReading {get; set;}
}
```

and a viewmodel like this (I removed the `INotifyPropertyChanged` part for better reading)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly Model MyModel;

    private int _actualReading;
    public int ActualReading
    {
        get { return _actualReading; }
        set { _actualReading = value; }
    }

    public ViewModel(Model model)
    {
        MyModel = model;
        ActualReading = model.ActualReading;
    }

    public Model GetModel()
    {
        MyModel.ActualReading = ActualReading;

        return MyModel;
    }
}
```

When you create the `ViewModel` instances you initialize it with the coresponding `Model` instance. When you have implemented this you can add your check in an easy way like this.

```
private int _actualReading;
public int ActualReading
{
    get { return _actualReading; }
    set
    {
        if (value >= MyModel.ActualReading)
        {
            _actualReading = value;
        }
        else
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Meter readings should not be smaller than previous value.", "Error", "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```